# How iOS get the image url from Ruby Rails assets folder?

Tags: ios, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I need let iOS download image from server.

- Server: Ruby Rails 4.0.2
- I try to send GET request from iOS to Rails firstly.
- Then Rails should respond image url (json format) to iOS.
- Then iOS use this image url to download this image from server file system.

  ### Problem is images are storing in Rails assets folder

### How to get the absolute whole assets folder path in Rails controller?

Comment: have u found any solution?

Comment: Yes, thank you Agent. I found two approaches, [1] store the images which will be downloaded in the rails's public folder. [2] Let rails read the image into memory and encode this image by base64 and encapsulate the image base64 string into json and response to ios.